# bashの補完候補を取得するには

Tags: bash

bashを対話環境で使用しているときにTabキーを押すと補完候補が一覧で表示されますが，これをシェルスクリプトから取得することは可能でしょうか？
つまり，現在の`$PATH`と`$PWD`（あるいは他に必要な環境変数があるかもしれません）と入力中の文字列が与えられて，それらから候補を文字列の配列で返す関数のようなイメージです．

Emacs LISPで言う`file-name-all-completions`に近いといえば分かりやすいでしょうか？

ご存知の方がいましたらお願い致します．

Answer (score 7):

SOでの同様の質問を参考にしました。  
[shell - bash completion script to complete file path after certain commandline options - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23998364/bash-completion-script-to-complete-file-path-after-certain-commandline-options)

`compgen -f` ではないでしょうか。

```
bash-3.2$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
bash-3.2$ ls
bash-3.2$ touch foo bar baz
bash-3.2$ ls
bar     baz     foo
bash-3.2$ compgen -f
bar
baz
foo
bash-3.2$ compgen -f ba
bar
baz
```

Comment: ありがとうございます．`-f`と`-c`でファイルとコマンド（alias, function含む）が取れるので，これらを組み合わせると遠回しですが同じものが得られそうですね．重複があるのが気になりますが……．